# ggplot update and not add a layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are ways to update settings of a given ggplot graph.

I want to save two files, one with the standard setting as png and another one as pdf but with a different label size.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('a;b;c','d;e;f'), b=c('A;B;C','D;E;F'),
                 x=c(1,2), y=c(2,3))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=a))

ggsave('test1.png',g)
ggsave('test2.pdf',g + geom_text(aes(label=a), size=10))
```

Is there a way to remove or update the old geom_text layer and not just add a layer to the graph?

Answer (score 3):

Look into `str(g)` and update relevant bits, in your case following should work:

```
g$layers[[2]]$geom_params$size <- 10
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to have a simpler basic object `g` and then add the layers you need

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()

ggsave('test1.png', g + geom_text(aes(label=a)))
ggsave('test2.pdf', g + geom_text(aes(label=a), size=10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the `size` argument inside the `aes` and then use `scale_size_manual`  to get different scales.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=a, size="size"), show_guide = FALSE)
g + scale_size_manual(values=c(size = 10))
```